# Why is jQuery.getJSON() flattening my javascript dictionary?

Tags: javascript, python, json, pyramid

I'm having a big issue with transmitting a javascript dictionary via the jQuery.getJSON() method to my server.  I have this dictionary declared in jscript:

```
data = {'a': 1, b:{'c':2, 'd':3}};
```

When I call:

```
jQuery.getJSON("myurl", data, callback)
```

the server receives a dictionary with these values:

```
{'a':1, 'b[c]':2, 'b[d]':3}.
```

Notice that the sub-dictionary was flattened by combining the 'b' key with the subkeys 'c' and 'd'.  This is incredibly obnoxious for highly nested data.

I admit I'm not sure if this is an issue with javascript and JSON serializing or if it has to with Python and Pyramid, the web framework which receives the data.  I've tried stringifying before sending the data as well as using Python's json library to deserialize it, but I only get errors.

Any help, please?

Comment: Are you REALLY using single quotes? Try changing them to double quotes in that case.  Also put quotes on "b"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Please note that this is not JSON, but a Javascript object literal. Using single quotes is perfectly fine, just like not using quotes at all for property names.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - yes, hard to tell for sure from the question if this is the serialized object or literal, but not being serialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the data is sent is correct.

The data field is intended to be data to be sent via HTTP.  If you send that via an HTTP get, you will see the parameters in the query string.

```
myurl?a=1&b%5Bc%5D=2&b%5Bd%5D=3
```

Unescaped URL:

```
myurl?a=1&b[c]=2&b[d]=3
```

If you want to send JSON to the server, you will need to stringify it. with [JSON.stringify()](http://www.json.org/js.html) You will need to include a JSON library for pre-IE8 support.

You need to assign the stringified data to a variable.

```
jQuery.getJSON("myurl",{data: JSON.stringify(data)}, callback);
```

This will be passed to your server in a variable called `data`.

Comment: Indeed I did try using stringify: jQuery.getJSON("myurl", JSON.stringify(data), callback) and it didn't fix the problem, unless I was handling it improperly on the the backend.  In python, I captured the data with a variable,  imported the json library and called json.loads(data), that threw an error saying "expected string or buffer".  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to assign the stringified data to a variable.  `jQuery.getJSON("myurl",{data: JSON.stringify(data)}, callback);`  This will be passed to your server in a variable called `data`

Comment: @Gazler - Thank you thank you thank you.  Stringifying it and assigning it to a variable inside the getJSON call did the trick.

Comment: @J-bob Glad to hear it.  I'll edit that into my answer so you can accept.